# Configurações de banner de instalação de PWA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, app, pwa

Tenho um PWA que foi elaborado utilizando VueJS e gostaria de saber se é possível exibir o banner de instalação mais de uma vez, pois atualmente ele só questiona uma vez se o usuário deseja instalar o PWA.

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer aparecer o banner mais de uma vez, por exemplo: o usuário acessou o site usando seu smartphone quando estava usando dados móveis e foi questionado sobre a instalação do PWA, porém ele clicou no X para fechar o banner, mas ao chegar em casa ele quer instalar pois nesse momento ele disponibiliza de wi-fi, porém ao acessar dessa vez o banner não aparece.

Se for possível fazer o banner aparecer novamente, como fazer isso??

Obs.: Já pesquisei nas documentações e nada fala sobre isso, mas também não fala de aparecer somente uma única vez...

Comment: Já encontrei a solução para o que eu precisava. O banner só é mostrado uma vez, se o usuário não instalar o app o banner só será mostrado de novo quando(e se) o usuário limpar o cache do navegador, está disponível neste link: https://appyourself.net/kb/en/articles/what-are-web-app-banners-and-how-many-times-do-they-appear-inside-the-pwa/

Comment: vc pode responder sua própria pergunta ao invez de deixar um comentário, assim vc ajuda quem tiver a mesma dúvida no futuro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já encontrei a solução para o que eu precisava.

O banner só é mostrado uma vez, se o usuário não instalar o app o banner só será mostrado de novo quando(e se) o usuário limpar o cache do navegador, está disponível neste [link](https://appyourself.net/kb/en/articles/what-are-web-app-banners-and-how-many-times-do-they-appear-inside-the-pwa/).
Porém quando se trata do pop-up de permissão de notificações é possível permitir, negar ou fazer ele requisitar permissão novamente alterando as configurações do site...